# array, which has been sent by laravel, becomes backwards when I used it from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I do this in controller

```
$actions = array('' => 'Select Action Name') + Action::lists('name' , 'id');
```

and then I send the $actions array to the view.

In the Javascript:

```
<script>
    var actions = {{json_encode($actions) }};
    /*for (var key in actions){
        console.log(key, actions[key]);
    }*/
    var options = "";
    for(var key in actions){
        options = options+ ('<option value="'+key+'">'+actions[key]+"</option>");
    }
    var select = '<select name="action_id">' + options + "</select>";
    console.log(select);

</script>
```

Print `select` results in:

```
<select name="action_id">
    <option value="1">Remove White Space</option>
    <option value="2">extract map latitude</option>
    <option value="3">Extract map longitude</option>
    <option value="">Select Action Name</option>
</select>
```

The array is backwards, as the first option should be the one with `Select Action Name` but is the last option.

Comment: or this might be possible that you are getting your values that way.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but you can always reverse your array using `reverse()` function like this `var reversedAction= action.reverse()`

Comment: Use [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) instead of `+`.

Comment: @Ben where exactly please? I have too many `+`s :)

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent on `$actions = array('' => 'Select Action Name') + Action::lists('name' , 'id');`, `array_unshift` prepends elements to an array.

Comment: I'm guessing its because you aren't giving it an index, so it goes last. Try `$actions = array(0 => 'Select Action Name') ...`

Comment: @Alex yes you right. that was the problem, but I don't want it to have any value

Comment: @Alex write an answer to accept it please. you comment was the correct answer for me.

Comment: @Anastasie Laurent I have written an answer. Thanks and good luck with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your array element an index of 0:

```
$actions = array(0 => 'Select Action Name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using string as keys to your array, you are not getting the ordering you would have had you used an integer based array

For your task, an easy solution would be to pass two arrays to your javascript, one containing

```
$actions = array('Select Action Name')
```

Send your names in another array

```
$names = Action::lists('name' , 'id');
```

Now modify your scripts like this

```
<script>
var actions = {{json_encode($actions) }};
var names = {{json_encode($names) }};
/*for (var key in actions){
    console.log(key, actions[key]);
}*/
var options = "";
options = options+ ('<option value="''">'+actions[0]+"</option>");

for(var key in names){
    options = options+ ('<option value="'+key+'">'+names[key]+"</option>");
}
var select = '<select name="action_id">' + options + "</select>";
console.log(select);

</script>
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. But I have got an answer already. many thanks